# Search Spreadsheet for certain values from Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I want to use Word VBA to find all words in the spreadsheet between brackets.

I got the 'find' routine to work perfectly inside Excel VBA, but when trying to transfer the code into Word, I get an error. Here is the code (the error is in the bolded line `.Find`, just beneath `n = 1 to 100`. Error is `Object doesn't support method`:

```
Function ScanExcelforVariables(ExcelPath, WorkbookToWorkOn)
Dim WORDIS As String
Dim N As Integer
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String
Dim ALLVARS As String
Dim sText As String
Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
Dim oXL As Object
Dim oXLwb As Object
If BeginTxtIDB = "" Then SetBoundaryMarks
'If Excel is running, get a handle on it; otherwise start a new instance
On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelWasNotRunning = True
    'Set oXL = New Excel.Application
End If
On Error goto 0
If Dir(AddLastSlash(ExcelPath) & WorkbookToWorkOn) <> "" Then
Set oXLwb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(filename:=AddLastSlash(ExcelPath) & WorkbookToWorkOn, ReadOnly:=True)
End If
oXL.Visible = True
Set oWS = oXLwb.worksheets(1)
oWS.Range("A1").Select
With oWS
For N = 1 To 100
    **.Find(what:="[", After:=.ActiveCell, LookAt:=2, _
        SearchOrder:=1, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False).Activate**
    'to break out of looping:    
    If .ActiveCell.Address = FIRSTCELL Then Exit Function

    FIRSTCELL = .ActiveCell.Address
    sText= .ActiveCell.text
    On Error Resume Next
    openPos = 1
    Do Until openPos = 0
        openPos = InStr(closePos, sText, "[")
        If openPos = 0 Then Exit Do
        On Error Resume Next
        closePos = InStr(openPos, sText, "]")
        On Error Resume Next
        midBit = Mid(sText, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)
        If InStr(ALLVARS, "|" & midBit & "|") Then
            'DO NOTHING, VAR EXISTS
        Else
            ALLVARS = ALLVARS & "|" & midBit
        End If
    Loop
    closePos = 1
Next N
End With
MsgBox ALLVARS
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome, Roy1953. It looks like you didn't `Dim oWS`. Also, you probably want a reference if you're running Excel from a Word macro. In the VB editor, click Tools > References and select Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.

Comment: (But don't select the reference to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library if the people running your macro won't have it selected.)

Comment: I am afraid that wasn't it, but I was able to simplify the question. Replace the long bolded code after n= 1 to 100 with just:

oWS.Cells.Find(what:="[").Activate

Comment: I am afraid that wasn't it, but I was able to simplify the question. Replace the long bolded code after n= 1 to 100 with just:

**oWS.Cells.Find(what:="[").Activate**

The first cell containg "[" is found and activated, but I cann do anything else. What I really want to do is get the text of the cell. This should work:

`ValInCell = oXLwb.ActiveCell.Text`  (but it doesn't. I still get object deosn't support property.)

Comment: Remove the period before `ActiveCell`, which isn't a worksheet property. See [Application.ActiveCell property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell) and [Window.ActiveCell property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.activecell). Also, you might use a range, as in `Dim OneCell as Range` and `For Each OneCell In oWS.UsedRange.Cells`. Also, you might copy from cells to arrays, which run fast. See Chip Pearson's advice, [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).